# Get most commented posts in django with django comments

Tags: django, comments

I'm trying to get the ten most commented posts in my django app, but I'm unable to do it because I can't think a proper way.

I'm currently using the django comments framework, and I've seen a possibility of doing this with [aggregate or annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) , but I can figure out how.

The thing would be:

- Get all the posts
- Calculate the number of comments per post (I have a comment_count method for that)
- Order the posts from most commented to less
- Get the first 10 (for example)

Is there any "simple" or "pythonic" way to do this? I'm a bit lost since the comments framework is only accesible via template tags, and not directly from the code (unless you want to modify it)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that you need to use the annotation and aggregation features.  What you need to do is group by and get a count of the `object_pk` of the `Comment` model:

```
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment
from django.db.models import Count

o_list = Comment.objects.values('object_pk').annotate(ocount=Count('object_pk'))
```

This will assign something like the following to `o_list`:

```
[{'object_pk': '123', 'ocount': 56},
 {'object_pk': '321', 'ocount': 47},
 ...etc...]
```

You could then sort the list and slice the top 10:

```
top_ten_objects = sorted(o_list, key=lambda k: k['ocount'])[:10]
```

You can then use the values in `object_pk` to retrieve the objects that the comments are attached to.

Comment: This solution appears to be more clean than the proposed by @j_syk I'm going to try it, thanks :)

Comment: I have a new question, how I'm supposed to acces the Post objets through this reversal relation? I wanted to obtain the title if possible :)

Comment: The output is not what expected. It repeats the entries: [{'object_pk': u'1', 'ocount': 1}, {'object_pk': u'1', 'ocount': 1}, {'object_pk': u'2', 'ocount': 1}] in this case it should be [{'object_pk': u'1', 'ocount': 2}, {'object_pk': u'2', 'ocount': 1}]

Answer (score 2):

Annotate is going to be the preferred way, partially because it will reduce db queries and it's basically a one-liner. While your theoretical loop would work, I bet your comment_count method relies on querying comments for a given post, which would be 1 query per post that you loop over- nasty!

```
posts_by_score = Comment.objects.filter(is_public=True).values('object_pk').annotate(
    score=Count('id')).order_by('-score')
post_ids = [int(obj['object_pk']) for obj in posts_by_score]
top_posts = Post.objects.in_bulk(post_ids)
```

This code is shameless adapted from [Django-Blog-Zinnia](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/blob/master/zinnia/templatetags/zinnia_tags.py#L87) (no affiliation)

Comment: Certainly my loop was based on querying all the post objects, which would end in a nasty superquery. Thanks for this solution :)